# Resgatar valor querystring pelo load do jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando chamar uma pagina através do load, essa pagina terá uma querystring que eu quero pega-la na pagina de chamada, porém o valor vem como null quando eu tento através do load, fora dele chamando a pagina sozinha, está tudo ok.

São 2 páginas, 1 principal e a 2 que trara um alert de acordo com o valor passado pela query

Página Principal (index.html)

```
<div id="content">resultado</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function carrega(v) {
    $("#content").load("/query/video.html?v="+ encodeURIComponent(v), function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            //alert("ocorreu um erro")
        } else {
            //alert("ok")
        }
    });
}

carrega("social");
</script>
```

Segunda página (video.html)

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var foo = getParameterByName('v');
alert(foo);
</script>
```

Se você fizer o teste chamado já a segunda pagina com a query assim /video.html?v=teste123 um alert de "teste123" vai aparecer, porém quando tento fazer isso pela página principal passando o parametro da query e trazendo o resultado por load, simplesmente da erro e o valor vem como null.

Alguém poderia me explicar aonde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

O seu código está correto, o problema ocorre onde o javascript é executado. Como você faz uma chamada Ajax e joga o conteúdo em "#content", o javascript é executado na mesma página que você está, ou seja, o "window.location.href" é o da página inicial (index.html). Você pode fazer um teste adicionando "v=teste" ao carregar a página principal.